# image filtering for high variance fields

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering, blur

I have an image like below. I would like to detect power lines. Although line detection algorithm is not restricted, I used hough transform and canny edge detection until now. However, as image has so much variance even in same region, unfortunatelly noise is so much. I used median blur, bilateral blur, lee filter but none of them is enough. What can be used for this task?

[image: Original Image]
Original image

[image: Canny Edges]
Canny without any enhencament

Unfortunatelly result almost same even if I apply the filters. What can I do to reduce variance on these grasss?

Comment: from that picture, it's impossible to extract power lines. see if you can grab an infrared picture. that might reveal the power lines (vs. vegetation), or not. -- Canny will only make your situation worse. don't use it for anything. -- this is for an autonomous drone, right? you need robust approaches. filtering around on a picture that shows "nothing" (hard to see even for humans), you will never get a robust solution for the task.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, it is little bit hard to see for a human too. However, image resolution is 1920x1080 so maybe it can be possible if you open the image. Actually I am not working to make a autonomous drone. There are many images like that and I would like to count how many power lines there are. There are some deep learning aproaches but it would take so much time as their source codes are not available.